# How to update values of a 2D matrix in the console?

Tags: c, matrix, console, codeblocks, c99

So I was doing nothing and decided to practice my C skill trying to replicate the snake game in the console. I managed to create the algorithm that will move the snake in the 2D matrix based on 'w' 'a' 's' 'd' keys, once I get the game going I will change those the arrow keys. However I ran into a couple problems; first, I start with one '*' representing the snake in the middle of the matrix, and once I press one of the movement keys (w, a, s, d) I have to press enter in order for it to move. I would like a continuous key listener so that I don't have to press enter. Secondly, every time I try to update the matrix with the snake new position, it just prints a new matrix underneath the old one, I would like for it to update the values of the original matrix (I tried using \b and \r for this, none worked). Any help is appreciated, I'm using c99 to write this program. There is still a lot to be done, but this the base that I would like to get working before going further into the project.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define FLUSH while(getchar() != '\n')

int lines = 25;
int colums = 25;

void keyListener(int*, int*);
void printField(int lin, int col, char[][col], int*, int*);

int main()
{
    char field[lines][colums];

    int posX = lines/2;
    int posY = colums/2;

    int game = 1;

    while(game)
    {
        printField(lines, colums, field, &posX, &posY);
        keyListener(&posX, &posY);
        if(posX < 0 || posX >= lines || posY < 0 || posY >= colums){
            game = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Game Over!");
    return 0;
}

void keyListener(int* posX, int* posY){
    char ch = getchar();
    FLUSH;
    switch(tolower(ch)){
    case 'w' :
        *posX = *posX - 1;
        break;
    case 'a' :
        *posY = *posY - 1;
        break;
    case 's' :
        *posX = *posX + 1;
        break;
    case 'd' :
        *posY = *posY + 1;
        break;
    }
    return;
}

void printField(int lin, int col, char field[][colums], int* posX, int* posY){
    for(int i = 0; i < lin; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            if(i == *posX && j == *posY){
                field[i][j] = '*';
            }
            else{
                field[i][j] = ' ';
            }
            printf("%c ", field[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    field[*posX][*posY] = ' ';
    return;
}
```

Comment: The solution: don't use the console... the problems you just described are common features of consoles. (I guess you can fix the problem with the new matrices appearing beneath the old ones by clearing the console, but that's already platform-dependent code.)

Comment: So there is no way to this in the console?

Comment: I just created a snake game last weekend that runs in different terminals/consoles: https://github.com/Zirias/cursedsnake -- you might be interested in using the `curses` API, there are implementations for all kinds of consoles/terminals.

Comment: In the old days of `DOS`, it as quite easy to directly read and write the screen memory. Nowadays, `Windows` provides a `Console API` to access `Console` buffers. See [here](http://cecilsunkure.blogspot.de/2011/11/windows-console-game-writing-to-console.html) for example code.

Comment: To add to my comment, using `curses`, you get your program to run on a variety of *UNIX* platforms that come with `curses`, on *Linux*, *FreeBSD* and the like using `ncurses` and on *Windows* and *DOS* using `pdcurses`. That's some serious portability :)

Comment: So far I used `system("cls")` to clear console window and `getche()` for the continuous key listener. I will take a look at your game Felix, it looks way more complex than what I plan to do.

Comment: I'm new to this whole thing, I don't even know what curses is, I have to take a look at it.

Comment: @AlexandreKrabbe it's a standard API hiding all the stuff *concrete* terminals/consoles need behind a unified interface. You write your code *once*, compile it with an implementation of `curses` for your target platform, and you're done ;) edit: in fact, my game was my personal attempt to learn the `curses` interface :)

Comment: I see that interesting, gonna take a look into it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: for starters, I recommend the [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/index.html). Although it's specifically about `ncurses`, all implementations of `curses` are compatible, so this will work as well if you use [`pdcurses`](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) on windows.